# nohup command only works in relative directory

Tags: python, linux, nohup

I'm attempting to run a python script via nohup, and calling out the full path to it throws `no such file or directory`.

Examples:

```
nohup python3 ./script.py
```

Works

```
nohup python3 /full/path/to/file/script.py
```

Does not work.

`cat nohup.out`

```
Python: can't open file '/full/path/to/file/script.py':
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Why can't `nohup` find the file if I give it the full path, but can if I'm in the directory?

Comment: Sounds like you've just got the path wrong. Can you copy-paste (not transcribe or censor) the exact path you use, along with the exact output of `pwd`?

Comment: The error message seems to indicate that's not the same thing.

Comment: error messages don't lie ;-)

Answer (score 0):

It also works in an absolute path. Below is an example of it.

I am printing Linux server time through python script with both absolute an relative path.

```
[root@ip-172-31-11-214 tmp]# pwd
/tmp
[root@ip-172-31-11-214 tmp]# ls -lrth
total 4.0K
-rw-rw-r-- 1 ec2-user ec2-user 113 Aug  9 20:28 test.py
[root@ip-172-31-11-214 tmp]# nohup python test.py
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
[root@ip-172-31-11-214 tmp]# cat nohup.out
This line will be printed.
2019-08-09 20:29:37.417722
[root@ip-172-31-11-214 tmp]# cd /root/
[root@ip-172-31-11-214 ~]# pwd
/root
[root@ip-172-31-11-214 ~]# nohup python /tmp/test.py
nohup: ignoring input and appending output to ‘nohup.out’
[root@ip-172-31-11-214 ~]# cat /root/nohup.out
This line will be printed.
2019-08-09 20:30:26.057960
[root@ip-172-31-11-214 ~]#
```